# OpenCV 3.3 dnn.readNetFromTensorflow() throws error: Unknown layer type Cast in op ToFloat

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

First,I use the OpenCV 3.3 and the Python 3.6.

When I use
`net=cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('MobileNetSSD.prototxt.txt','MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel')`, it works.

The question is when I load the tensorflow module,there is an error:
My code is

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph_face.pb')
```

The wrong message is

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:/real-time-object-detection/real_time_object_detection.py", line 34, in <module>
        net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph_face.pb')
    cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.3.0\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:883: error: (-2) Unknown layer type Cast in op ToFloat in function cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v1::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::populateNet
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072498/evaluation-of-tensorflow-model-with-opencv-fails

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work or could you share an update?

Comment: Hi ! Could you use text graph in this [comment](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10431#issuecomment-360120874) and let us know.